# Selecting everything from a cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

Currently I am using the following query [as described here](http://www.myhowto.org/bigdata/2013/11/04/scanning-the-entire-cassandra-column-family-with-cql/) to page through the table:

```
 select token(id) as token_id, description, title from my_table where token(id) >= -8987733732583272758 limit 10;
```

The next page would the be queried with the last token of the previous query:

```
 select token(id) as token_id, description, title from my_table where token(id) >= -7325522621472161647 limit 10;
```

Now my question is: Is this correct? Is the result-set always ordered by the token(id), so that I do not skip any rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think since Cassandra 2.0 there is automatic paging available if you use the java driver.  So the token approach may not be the best way to page through a table.

See more information here: [automatic paging](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0).

Answer (score 1):

thanks Jim! The link you provided actually had all the information I needed :-)

> In the case we need to iterate over an entire table, we’ll have to use the token() function are partition key aren’t ordered across the cluster, but token of partition key are. So the two previous queries become:

```
SELECT * FROM images LIMIT 100;
SELECT * FROM images WHERE token(image_id) > token([Last image ID received]) LIMIT 100;
```